# Program is skipping while loop to read each line in a file

Tags: c, while-loop

I am creating a small project where at first the program checks if the file is empty. If the file is empty, it skips the `while` loop as normal. However, when the file is not empty it is still skipping the `while` loop.

```c
read_list = fopen("list.txt", "r");
long fileSize = 0;
fseek(read_list, 0, SEEK_END);
fileSize = ftell(read_list);

if (fileSize != 0) {
    char line[256];

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), read_list)) {
        printf("%s", line);
    }
}
```

Comment: `fseek(read_list, 0, SEEK_END)` is placing the cursor at the end of the file

Comment: You don't really need the file size check

Comment: Thanks, both of you. I did not know that fseek will place the cursor at the end of the file and that was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewind the file

```
rewind(read_list);
//reading loop
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the rewind(read_list), and it worked. Thanks for the fast response.